# Azure Media Services v3 - Preset for generating captions: Azure Media Indexer 2 Preview

Tags: caption, azure-media-services

Is there a **Preset** for generating captions like the v2 **Azure Media Indexer 2 Preview** media processor, found in V2?

Hypothetical example:

```
var transform = await _client.Transforms.GetAsync(ResourceGroup, AccountName, TranscribeTransformName);

if (transform == null)
{
    var output = new[]
    {
        new TransformOutput
        {
            Preset = new BuiltInMediaIndexerPreset
            {
                PresetName = "Azure Media Indexer 2 Preview"
            }
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution by examining the code comments from Go To References.

```
var transform = await _client.Transforms.GetAsync(ResourceGroup, AccountName, TranscribeTransformName);

if (transform == null)
{
    var output = new[]
    {
        new TransformOutput(new VideoAnalyzerPreset("en-US", InsightsType.AudioInsightsOnly))
    };

    transform = await _client.Transforms.CreateOrUpdateAsync(ResourceGroup, AccountName, TranscribeTransformName, output);
}


/// <summary>
/// Initializes a new instance of the VideoAnalyzerPreset class.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="audioLanguage">The language for the audio payload in
/// the input using the BCP-47 format of 'language tag-region' (e.g:
/// 'en-US'). The list of supported languages are, 'en-US', 'en-GB',
/// 'es-ES', 'es-MX', 'fr-FR', 'it-IT', 'ja-JP', 'pt-BR', 'zh-CN',
/// 'de-DE', 'ar-EG', 'ru-RU', 'hi-IN'. If not specified, automatic
/// language detection would be employed. This feature currently
/// supports English, Chinese, French, German, Italian, Japanese,
/// Spanish, Russian, and Portuguese. The automatic detection works
/// best with audio recordings with clearly discernable speech. If
/// automatic detection fails to find the language, transcription would
/// fallback to English.</param>
/// <param name="insightsToExtract">The type of insights to be
/// extracted. If not set then based on the content the type will
/// selected.  If the content is audi only then only audio insights are
/// extraced and if it is video only. Possible values include:
/// 'AudioInsightsOnly', 'VideoInsightsOnly', 'AllInsights'</param>
public VideoAnalyzerPreset(string audioLanguage = null, InsightsType? insightsToExtract = null);
```

Answer (score 0):

Does captioning work for videos encoded with "AdaptiveStreaming" as well?